# How to save/overwrite the newly created copy of excel workbook with an appended name to a new partition

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a small automation project where I can send my workbook to a friend by saving it on a server and also by sending emails(now the server part is not important and I will work on it later).

Now I have been able to create a new file and copy all the contents. What I have done is copy all the sheets and save it in a new folder in the same directory. What I really want to do is create a new directory in a different partition say D:\Excel and save it in there with each of my friends having their own file names. And I also want to append the current date to the filename of the new workbook that is created and if a filename with date already exists for the particular friend, I want the new file to overwrite the existing file.

I have for this project already automated the sending of emails and the only problem there has been that I have not been able to send the email at a preset time.Whenever I click on send email,it goes automatically rather than the set time. Can anyone show me the right way to automate these things?

```
Private Sub Create_Click()


  Dim FileExtStr As String
  Dim FileFormatNum As Long
  Dim dUMMY1 As Workbook
  Dim Destwb As Workbook
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim DateString As String
  Dim FolderName As String

  Dim dt As String, wbNam As String



  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  End With

 'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
  Set dUMMY1 = ThisWorkbook

 'Create new folder to save the new files in
 DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
 FolderName = dUMMY1.Path & "\" & dUMMY1.Name & " " & DateString
 MkDir FolderName

 'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
 For Each sh In dUMMY1.Worksheets

    'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
    If sh.Visible = -1 Then
        sh.Copy

        'Set Destwb to the new workbook
        Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
        With Destwb
            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                'You use Excel 97-2003
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                'You use Excel 2007-2013
                If dUMMY1.Name = .Name Then
                    MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                    GoTo GoToNextSheet
                Else
                    Select Case dUMMY1.FileFormat
                    Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    Case 52:
                        If .HasVBProject Then
                            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                        Else
                            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        End If
                    Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                    Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        End With

        'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
        If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
            With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).Select
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If


        'Save the new workbook and close it
         With Destwb
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                  & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                    FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
            .Close False
        End With


    End If
GoToNextSheet:
  Next sh





 MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 End With



End Sub


Private Sub Send_Click()

  Dim OutApp As Object
  Dim OutMail As Object

  Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:45:00"), "Auto_Update"
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  On Error Resume Next
  With OutMail
    .to = "abc@def.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Testing "
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    .Send
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the file that I have been working on:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7uN4B3mxUlZUjV6VnpLdUpQeEU

Comment: sounds like a task you'd have to set up in the task scheduler.

Comment: Your `Application.Ontime` is set to run `Auto_Update` - which isn't listed here. Perhaps what you want to do is to Send email at that time instead of schedule the sub call then send email immediately.